# Regular expression for UTF-8 language

Tags: java, regex

my application also supports punjabi(\u0A00-\u0A7F)
i tried following code

```
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile("\u0A00-\u0A7F ");
    Matcher classMatcher = classPattern.matcher("ਭਾਸ਼ਾ ਸੰਦ");
            if (classMatcher.find()) {
              System.out.println("yes");
            }else{
                System.out.println("no");
            }
```

i am getting "no" as output though i provided punjabi charactes in matcher()

any idea why??

Comment: Rather than using the literal `[\u0A00-\u0A7F]`, why don’t you use `\p{InGurmukhi}` instead? It’s symbolic now instead of a magic number, which is preferable. You can use it alone in a regex or as part of an enclosing character class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should that pattern be `"[\u0A00-\u0A7F ]"`? It looks to me like you're trying to match four characters in a specific order, but give the matcher six characters as input.

Answer (score 3):

```
[\u0A00-\u0A7F ]*
```

Without the asterisk, you'll match only a single character. You can replace the `*` with `+`, then empty strings won't be accepted.

Take a look at the [Pattern class JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). It's extremely useful to get a good and quick understanding of regexes.

Answer (score 1):

because "asdsa  " is not punjabi [the pattern you gave will look for  pubjabi chars ,a dn abc aren't]

Comment: `[\u0A00-\u0A7F]`  same as `[a-zA-Z] a through z or A through Z, inclusive (range)` and make sure `ਭਾਸ਼ਾ ਸੰਦ` all these chars belong to provided range